# Constant time password digest compares using Crypto++

Tags: c++, hash, crypto++, pbkdf2

I'm writing a program which hashes passwords with the [pbkdf2 method using cryptopp](http://cryptopp.com/).

I have problems with validating the passwords. I have tried to compare the output in "length-constant" time but it always fails and returns false.

```
// a and b are std strings containing the output of the DeriveKey function

unsigned diff = a.length() ^ b.length();
for(unsigned i = 0; i < a.length() && i < b.length(); i++)
{
      diff |= (unsigned)a[i] ^ (unsigned)b[i];
}

bool equal = diff == 0;
```

Is using "slow equals" even the right way to validate pbkdf2 passwords? I am a bit confused on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm writing a program which hashes passwords with the pbkdf2 method using cryptopp.

You linked to the Crypto++ main page, and not a your particular use of PBKDF. Here's [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27261798/608639) just in case (it uses the IETF test vectors from [RFC 6070](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt)):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    byte password[] ="password";
    size_t plen = strlen((const char*)password);

    byte salt[] = "salt";
    size_t slen = strlen((const char*)salt);

    int c = 1;
    byte derived[20];

    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA1> pbkdf2;
    pbkdf2.DeriveKey(derived, sizeof(derived), 0, password, plen, salt, slen, c);

    string result;
    HexEncoder encoder(new StringSink(result));

    encoder.Put(derived, sizeof(derived));
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    cout << "Derived: " << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

> I have tried to compare the output in "length-constant" time but it always fails and returns false.

Crypto++ has a constant time compare built in. Use `VerifyBufsEqual` from [`misc.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/misc_8h_source.html). The source is available in [`misc.cpp`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/misc_8cpp_source.html).

```sh
$ cd cryptopp
$ grep -R VerifyBufsEqual *
cryptlib.cpp:   return VerifyBufsEqual(digest, digestIn, digestLength);
default.cpp:    if (!VerifyBufsEqual(check, check+BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE))
fipstest.cpp:   if (!VerifyBufsEqual(expectedModuleMac, actualMac, macSize))
fipstest.cpp:   if (VerifyBufsEqual(expectedModuleMac, actualMac, macSize))
misc.cpp:bool VerifyBufsEqual(const byte *buf, const byte *mask, size_t count)
misc.h:CRYPTOPP_DLL bool CRYPTOPP_API VerifyBufsEqual(const byte *buf1, const byte *buf2, size_t count);
pssr.cpp:   valid = VerifyBufsEqual(representative + representativeByteLength - u, hashIdentifier.first, hashIdentifier.second) && valid;
pubkey.cpp: return VerifyBufsEqual(representative, computedRepresentative, computedRepresentative.size());
secblock.h:     return m_size == t.m_size && VerifyBufsEqual(m_ptr, t.m_ptr, m_size*sizeof(T));
```

What I'm not clear about: `VerifyBufsEqual` is predicated upon buffers of equal lengths. I'm not sure if its OK to overlook the "not-equal length" case.

---

There's also a question on the Information Stack Exchange that may be relevant: [Timing attacks on password hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/9192/29925). But I'm not certain if/how it generalizes to arbitrary buffer compares.

The question piqued my interest in an answer to the general problem (the question has always been there): [Constant time compares when array sizes are not equal?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/77428/29925). That should tell us if  we have the proper tools in `VerifyBufsEqual` (Crypto++), `CRYPTO_memcmp` (OpenSSL), etc.